# Display all information with data.info() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would display all information of my data frame which contains more than 100 columns with .info() from pandas but it won't :

```
data_train.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 85529 entries, 0 to 85528
Columns: 110 entries, ID to TARGET
dtypes: float64(40), int64(19), object(51)
memory usage: 71.8+ MB
```

I would like it displays like this :

```
data_train.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10886 entries, 0 to 10885
Data columns (total 12 columns):
datetime      10886 non-null object
season        10886 non-null int64
holiday       10886 non-null int64
workingday    10886 non-null int64
weather       10886 non-null int64
temp          10886 non-null float64
atemp         10886 non-null float64
humidity      10886 non-null int64
windspeed     10886 non-null float64
casual        10886 non-null int64
registered    10886 non-null int64
count         10886 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(8), object(1)
memory usage: 1020.6+ KB
```

But the problem seems to be the high number of columns from my previous data frame. I would like to show all values including non null values (NaN).

Comment: You need to pass `null_counts=True`  for that. I've edited James' post.

Answer (score 45):

You can pass optional arguments `verbose=True` and `show_counts=True` (`null_counts=True` deprecated since pandas 1.2.0)  to the `.info()` method to output information for all of the columns

pandas >=1.2.0: `data_train.info(verbose=True, show_counts=True)`

pandas <1.2.0: `data_train.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)`